# Ruby - Manipulating Time/DateTime by the Hour/Day?

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

Where can I find some examples on how to manipulate the time objects by days/hours/etc?

I would like to do this:

```
time.now_by_hour #=> "Tue Jun 15 23 MST 2010"
time.now_by_day #=> ""Tue Jun 15 MST 2010"
time.now_by_hour - 4.weeks - 3.days #=> "Sat May 15 MST 2010"
```

What is the recommended order of operations?  The reason for this is I would like to run through lists of times and sort them by date to the hour, not to the minute and second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You chould check out `active_support` gem for this. It has nifty time/date manipulation methods so you can do stuff like this:

```
Time.now - 3.weeks - 2.days - 5.hours - 35.minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Time.strftime 
([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298)) ?

Comment: Now it makes me wonder if viatropos wanted manipulation of string representation or of the date/time itself .)

Answer (score 0):

Install Active Support:

`$gem install activesupport`

then in your Ruby script, do

`require 'active_support/core_ext`

That allows you to do things like these:

```
Time.now + 1.year
3.seconds.ago
```

etc.